# Unable to set grid width property

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, width

On my personal page i have a `section` with Skills, showing how much i know each programing language (i do not think it is accurate but whatever). I can seem to set width on the Skill grid to behave as all the other grids.

**This is how it looks:**
[image]

**This is what i need it to look like (except with the skills instead of email):**
[image]

**Here you can access the code:**

https://codepen.io/wodosharlatan/pen/OJwQNLL

I solved the contact section by using `grid-column: span 2;`, but it does not work for this section, i also tried setting the grid width to 100% but it did not do anything

*Any help or ideas are appreciated, if you need more code drop me a comment*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting grid with two columns instead of one for "medium devices".

```
.about__container,
.skills__container,
.portfolio__content,
.contact__container,
.footer__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
```

replace it in your media query for medium sized devices with:

```
.about__container,
.skills__container,
.portfolio__content,
.contact__container,
.footer__container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
```

Keep in mind these are combined selectors, so it will change styles for others containers also, but I hope you want to achieve full width for medium sized devices anyway.

P.S.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
```

just creates two equal columns and repeat function translates to:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
```

Also don't forget to cleanup spanning column code :-)

Comment: codepen https://codepen.io/ignasb/pen/dyjdMmB

Comment: It was not the solution since putting `grid-template-columns: 1fr;` on all the containers rigged the page but i removed the skills from all the containers and did this:                                                               `.skills__container{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  } `                                                                                                                                            And that worked like a charm

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  That is why I suggested to look into your combined selectors because that css rule is applied to multiple items. Good job figuring that out :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `skills__container` has an extra wrapping layer inside for the content, and might not actually apply the layout to its content.

Forked demo with modification: [codepen](https://codepen.io/john-zhuangzhuang-li/pen/qByxZyw)

Try remove the extra wrapping layer:

```
<div class="skills__container container grid">
  <!-- Removed extra wrapper  <div> -->
  <!--==================== SKILLS 1 ====================-->
  <div class="skills__content skills__open">
    <div class="skills__header">
      <i class="uil uil-brackets-curly skills__icon"></i>

      <div>
        <h1 class="skills__title">Frontend development</h1>
        <span class="skills__subtitle">More than a year</span>
      </div>

      <i class="uil uil-angle-down skills__arrow"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="skills__list grid">
      <div class="skills__data">
        <div class="skills__titles">
          <h3 class="skills__name">CSS</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="skills__bar">
          <span class="skills__percentage skills__css"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="skills__data">
        <div class="skills__titles">
          <h3 class="skills__name">HTML</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="skills__bar">
          <span class="skills__percentage skills__html"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="skills__data">
        <div class="skills__titles">
          <h3 class="skills__name">JavaScript</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="skills__bar">
          <span class="skills__percentage skills__js"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--==================== SKILLS 2 ====================-->
  <div class="skills__content skills__close">
    <div class="skills__header">
      <i class="uil uil-database skills__icon"></i>

      <div>
        <h1 class="skills__title">Backend development</h1>
        <span class="skills__subtitle">Around 3 months</span>
      </div>

      <i class="uil uil-angle-down skills__arrow"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="skills__list grid">
      <div class="skills__data">
        <div class="skills__titles">
          <h3 class="skills__name">PHP</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="skills__bar">
          <span class="skills__percentage skills__php"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skills__data">
        <div class="skills__titles">
          <h3 class="skills__name">NODE JS</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="skills__bar">
          <span class="skills__percentage skills__node"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skills__data">
        <div class="skills__titles">
          <h3 class="skills__name">SQL</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="skills__bar">
          <span class="skills__percentage skills__sql"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--==================== SKILLS 3 ====================-->
  <div class="skills__content skills__close">
    <div class="skills__header">
      <i class="uil uil-code-branch skills__icon"></i>

      <div>
        <h1 class="skills__title">Miscellaneous Skills</h1>
        <span class="skills__subtitle">Time varies by skill</span>
      </div>

      <i class="uil uil-angle-down skills__arrow"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="skills__list grid">
      <div class="skills__data">
        <div class="skills__titles">
          <h3 class="skills__name">GIT</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="skills__bar">
          <span class="skills__percentage skills__git"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skills__data">
        <div class="skills__titles">
          <h3 class="skills__name">Bash</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="skills__bar">
          <span class="skills__percentage skills__bash"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skills__data">
        <div class="skills__titles">
          <h3 class="skills__name">C#</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="skills__bar">
          <span class="skills__percentage skills__c-sharp"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--   </div> -->
</div>
```

Comment: It was not what i wanted, BUT it helped me with other problem, thanks